# Parse API always Unreachable?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, reachability

I'm using Apple's Reachability framework, **"api.parse.com" is ALWAYS Unreachable**. Am I missing something?

In my viewDidLoad, I have this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];

    self.hostParseReachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:kParseConnectivityTestURL];
    [self.hostParseReachability startNotifier];
    [self updateInterfaceWithReachability:self.hostParseReachability];
```

Then I have the following Reachability methods:

```
-(void)reachabilityChanged:(NSNotification* )note
{
    Reachability* curReach = [note object];
    NSParameterAssert([curReach isKindOfClass:[Reachability class]]);
    [self updateInterfaceWithReachability:curReach];
}

- (void)updateInterfaceWithReachability:(Reachability *)reachability {
    NetworkStatus netStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

    if (reachability == self.internetReachability) {
        switch (netStatus) {
            case NotReachable:
                isConnectedToInternet = NO;
                break;
            case ReachableViaWWAN:
            case ReachableViaWiFi:
                isConnectedToInternet = YES;
                break;
        }
    }

    if (reachability == self.hostParseReachability) {
        switch (netStatus) {
            case NotReachable:
                isParseOnline = NO;
                break;
            case ReachableViaWWAN:
            case ReachableViaWiFi:
                isParseOnline = YES;
                break;
        }
    }
```

Parse is ALWAYS offline for me, but I can perform queries.

Comment: what is the URL that you are passing to Reachability because I have seen Reachability not working with https URLs.

Comment: @satheeshwaran Oops. Thanks for pointing that out! I included the https:// to the URL.

Answer (score 0):

They have a firewall blocking `ICMP` packets. If you need to check manually if everything is fine - you can try `curl`

If `parse` is unreachable, you'll get `kPLParseConnectionFailed` (in case of iOs app).